# Continuous and non-continuous functions in topology

Tags: general-topology

Consider the function $ f :\Bbb R  \to \Bbb Z$ defined in the following manner:
$f(x) = n$ when $x \in [n,n+1)$ for all $x \in\Bbb R$ and $n \in\Bbb Z$
(note: $f$ is just a function that rounds to the next lower integer)
For example the function $f$ gives the following mappings:
$$[–41,–40) \mapsto\; –41;\:\: [–17,–16) \mapsto\; –17;\:\: [117,118) \mapsto\; 117$$

Consider $\Bbb Z$ to have the digital line topology and determine a topology on $\Bbb R$ as required below.

> 1) State a topology on $\Bbb R$ where $f$ is a continuous function.  Using the open set definition for continuity, explain why your topology on $\Bbb R$ makes $f$ continuous.
>
> 2) State a topology on $\Bbb R$ where $f$ in NOT a continuous function.  Using the open set definition for continuity, explain why your topology on $\Bbb R$ makes $f$ not continuous.

I don't understand how this function can be non-continuous. To me this looks like it is continuous everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

If we're thinking of the normal topology on $\mathbb{R}$, the function $f$ "breaks" the domain at every integer. This is the notion of a discontinuity.

One definition of continuity is in terms of the function commuting with the taking of limits.

$$f\left(\lim_{x \to 118} x \right) = f(118) = 118$$
$$\lim_{x \to 118^-} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 118} 117 = 117$$
$$\lim_{x \to 118^+} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 118} 118 = 118$$

Answer (score 0):

For the usual topology, $ \{0\}$ is open in $\Bbb Z$, but for the usual topology of $\Bbb R $,

$f^{-1}( \{0\} ) = [0, 1)$ is **not** open

Hence $f$ is not continuous.

Now, take $P(\Bbb R)$  as your topology on $\Bbb R$, and $[0, 1) \in P(\Bbb R)$ is open. You can show that for this topology, $f$ is continuous (and every function is continuous)

Comment: What is P(R)? Is it just like f(x) or is it something else?

Comment: @bvt5050 : the power set of $\Bbb R$, i.e the set of the subsets of $\Bbb R$. You can prove that it's a topology if you didn't already do it

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot for the help. I appreciate it.